# Updating amount automatically jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm making a spreadsheet in which the user can input their expenses and the total will update automatically. The numbers in my HTML are starter numbers and I made them editable so the user can change them accordingly. The problem is that my JQuery no longer calculates the total after I change the amounts manually in the editable version. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
    
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.quantity').each(function() {
        $(calculateSum);
       });
   });

        function calculateSum() {
            var sum = 0;
            $(".quantity").each(function() {

        var value = $(this).text();
        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(value);
    }
    });
        $('#TotalValue').text(sum);    
    };
    
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>Rent</td>
            <td class="quantity" contentEditable="true" style = "text-align: right">400</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Food</td>
            <td class="quantity" contentEditable="true" style = "text-align: right">200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Entertainment</td>
            <td class="quantity" contentEditable="true" style = "text-align: right">100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Transportation</td>
            <td class="quantity" contentEditable="true" style = "text-align: right">50</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>   
        <tr>
        <th>Total</th>
            <td id="TotalValue" style = "text-align: right"></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot> 
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Code should be as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.quantity').on('keyup', function(){
    calculateSum();
 });
 function calculateSum(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('.quantity').each(function(){
    var val = $(this).text();
    val = isNaN(val) || $.trim(val) === "" ? 0 : parseFloat(val);
    sum += val;
});
$('#TotalValue').text(sum); 
}
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajtri/9anLtbkw/10/)

Comment: ok, look at this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/rajtri/9anLtbkw/14/